# How to switch between tab using shortcut key in RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application, there are multiple ViewParts and EditorParts open. I want to define a shortcut key to switching between these parts.

Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Custom KeyBinding sequence example :  <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>  to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Forward** direction using Eclipse RCP.

you press <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>  second  time to open
another editor and close previous editor using RCP Eclipse.

```
package rcp_demo.Toolbar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditorInput;

public class Forward_Editor extends AbstractHandler{

    static String Editor_name;  //  Active Editor name store in Temporary 
    static int cnt;             //  close editor count this variable
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();

        //Blank Editor Window to execute..
        if(editors.length==0)
        {
            //First time close editor can open Student_Editor
            if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Student_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
            //First time close editor can open Employee_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Employee_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name); 
                } catch (PartInitException e) {e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First time close editor can open Product_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Product_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("student Editor open");
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Close::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First Time call // empty editors 
            else{
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("student Editor open");
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }//End if condition

        //AvtiveEditor(Student_Editor) close to open Employee Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor"))
        {
            try {
                //page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.closeEditor(page.getActiveEditor(), true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Employee_Editor) close to open Product Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor"))
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);

                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);

            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Product_Editor) close to open Student Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor"))
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("stud>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //by default open Student Editor
        else 
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("stud_else>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

>Custom KeyBinding sequence example : <kbd> SHIFT + TAB </kbd> to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Backword** direction using Eclipse RCP.


package rcp_demo.Toolbar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditorInput;

public class Backword_Editor extends AbstractHandler{

    static String Editor_name;   // Active Editor name store in Temporary 
    static int cnt;

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        //Three object create in EditorInput 
        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
        System.out.println("Length : "+editors.length);

        if(editors.length==0)
        {
            //First time close editor can open Student_Editor
            if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Product_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            //First time close editor can open Employee_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Employee_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Student>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..student::"+Editor_name);

                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First time close editor can open Product_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Student_Editor"))
            {
                        try {
                            page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                            cnt=1;
                            Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                            System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);

                        } catch (PartInitException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            } 
            //First Time or empty editors to check this condition
            else{
                try {
                    page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("product Editor open");
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Product_Editor) close to open Employee Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("Employee Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Employee_Editor) close to open Student Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Emp:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("student Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Student_Editor) close to open Product Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //by default open Student Editor
        else 
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Custom KeyBinding sequence example :  <kbd>SHIFT + TAB</kbd>  to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Backword** direction using Eclipse RCP.

```
package rcp_demo.Toolbar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditorInput;

public class Backword_Editor extends AbstractHandler{

    static String Editor_name;   // Active Editor name store in Temporary 
    static int cnt;

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        //Three object create in EditorInput 
        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
        System.out.println("Length : "+editors.length);

        if(editors.length==0)
        {
            //First time close editor can open Student_Editor
            if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Product_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            //First time close editor can open Employee_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Employee_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Student>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..student::"+Editor_name);

                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First time close editor can open Product_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Student_Editor"))
            {
                        try {
                            page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                            cnt=1;
                            Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                            System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);

                        } catch (PartInitException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            } 
            //First Time or empty editors to check this condition
            else{
                try {
                    page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("product Editor open");
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Product_Editor) close to open Employee Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("Employee Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Employee_Editor) close to open Student Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Emp:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("student Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Student_Editor) close to open Product Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //by default open Student Editor
        else 
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Key Sequence

M1 means  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

M2 means <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

> plugin.xml

---

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command
                defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Toolbar.Forward_Editor"
                id="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.Forward_editor_open_cmd"
                name="Forward_Editor">
        </command>
        <command
                defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Toolbar.Backword_Editor"
                id="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.backwards_editor_open_cmd"
                name="Backword_Editor">
        </command>
    </extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key
                commandId="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.Forward_editor_open_cmd"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M1+TAB">
        </key>  
        <key
                commandId="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.backwards_editor_open_cmd"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M2+TAB">
        </key>              
</extension>
```